# ContextMenu click of DataGrid in view model

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have use the following code snippet to get the ContextMenu click of DataGrid in view model

Code Snippet[XAML]

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding GDCSource}" x:Name="dataGrid">
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu >
    <ContextMenu.Items>
        <MenuItem Header="Export To Excel" Command="{Binding ExportCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid}"/>  
    </ContextMenu.Items>
</ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Code Snippet[C#]

```
private BaseCommand exportcommand;

    public BaseCommand ExportCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (exportcommand == null)
                exportcommand = new BaseCommand(ExportCommandExcecuted);

            return exportcommand;
        }
    }

    public void ExportCommandExcecuted(object param)
    {
        var grid = param as GridDataControl;
    }
```

But I cannot get the Command parameter as DataGrid. Can you please look into this and provide suggestion to achieve this dataGrid in ViewModel. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if I should even tell you how to do this since your breaking MVVM if you are essentially doing this and I cannot figure out a reason for you wanting this functionality.

If you're not using MVVM, then you could try having your `MenuItem` such as

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding ExportCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget}"
          Header="Export To Excel" />
```

If you're using MVVM,

Just don't reference UI elements in the VM. You got the `ItemSource` collection in the VM. Raise a plain simple `ICommand` and all the data you need is available without you getting the `DataGrid` to the VM.

Comment: You would have to set the `PlacemenTarget` of `ContextMenu` in the XAML with the datagrid itself... like `<ContenxtMenu PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid}">`

Comment: @WPF-it No you don't "have to". OP's `ContextMenu` is within `<DataGrid.ContextMenu>` in xaml and if I replicate it exactly with just the `CommandParameter` switched, it works fine to get a reference to the `DataGrid`.